# Using setInterval in React delays component render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I have a parent component, `<App>`:

```
constructor() {
    super();            
    this.state = {
        transporterPos: 0
    }
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.timerId = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerId);
}

tick() {
    let transporterPos = this.state.transporterPos;
    transporterPos++;
    if (transporterPos > 7) {
        transporterPos = 0;
    }
    this.setState({ transporterPos: transporterPos });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Staves transporterPos={this.state.transporterPos}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The `<Staves>` component contains several `<Stave>` components, each of which contains several `<Note>` components. Each `<Note>` component is injected with a `className` conditional on its `active` property being `true`:

```
<div className="noteContainer" onClick={this.handleClick}>
    <div className={"note" + (this.props.active ? ' active' : '')}></div>
</div>
```

`handleClick()` is a method that toggles a `<Note>`'s `active` property. I'm not including all the code here to make this more readable. The problem is that when clicking on a `<Note>`, although its `active` property changes immediately, the styling given by the conditional `className` of 'active' is not visible **until the component is re-rendered at the next "tick" of the `setInterval` method**. In other words, rendering only seems to happen once every 1000ms. I would like it to happen immediately. Am I using `setInterval` wrong?

**Edit:**

In response to comments, here is the `handleClick` method (in `<Note>`):

```
handleClick() {
    this.props.toggleActive(this.props.pos);
}
```

This calls `toggleActive` in `<Stave>`:

```
toggleActive(pos) {
    this.props.notes[pos].active = !this.props.notes[pos].active;
}
```

`props.notes` here is part of `<App>`'s `state`, which is passed down to `<Stave>` (and which I didn't include in this question for the sake of brevity).

Comment: Please post the code present in `Staves`,  `Note` and `handleClick`

Comment: Post handleClick, yes

Comment: @Lucas I understand the clarity that would bring, but it would also make the question unfeasibly long. I'm hoping - though I could of course be wrong - that I am in principle misusing `setInterval`.

Comment: I think you don't use setState in handleClick, can you confirm that?

Comment: show the code that changes and passes in `active` - most likely it's not being changed via `setState` which is why a re-render isn't being triggered until your `tick`

Comment: @GluePear it's not clear who is changing the value of `active`. That I believe is first place to look to find why your code isn't working. So if you can at least show this logic, it would help.You can post the code in some paste service and post the link

Comment: pretty sure @FuzzyTree is right on this one.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've made an edit to include `handleClick()`

Comment: there's your problem - you may not mutate `this.props` directly

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks @FuzzyTree

Comment: I guess I have to push `toggleActive` further up to `<App>` so that I can use `setState`.

Comment: @GluePear yup - keep in mind when you mutate the prop directly in the child component, it will just get overwritten the next time the parent changes state and passes the props back down again

Comment: @FuzzyTree That worked - if you want to put it in an answer I can mark it right. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
toggleActive(pos) {
    this.props.notes[pos].active = !this.props.notes[pos].active;
}
```

The reason a re-render isn't being triggered is because `this.props` is mutated directly instead of with `setState`. Move `toggleActive` further up to where you can use `setState`.

If necessary you can pass the function as a prop to the child component and call it via `this.props.toggleActive()`

Besides not triggering a re-render, another reason `this.props` should never be mutated directly is because your changes will get overwritten whenever the parent changes state and passes props to its children.